# If I have 5 red balls and 9 blue balls and I remove 2 without replacement, what is the probability they will be of different colour?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, hypergeometric-function

I want to check my solution to this simple question. I use the hypergeometric distribution and so I solve this problem using:

$$\frac{{5\choose1} {9\choose1}}{14\choose2} = \frac{45}{91} $$

Is this correct?

Comment: yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinatorics work well, but you could have also chosen to work with a simple probability tree diagram, in that case:
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{different})=\mathbb{P}(RB)+\mathbb{P}(BR)=\frac{5}{14}\cdot \frac{9}{13}+\frac{9}{14}\cdot \frac{5}{13}=\frac{45}{91}.$$

Comment: Which is, of course, equal to $\tfrac{\tbinom 51\cdot\tbinom 91}{\tbinom{14}2}$